# jQuery highlight divs that match value in dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I have this jsfiddle which is working great, when you select one of the colours from the top list it highlights all divs that contain the same class

```
.$links = $('.link');
$links.click(function(e) {
    //Get our variables, simply $(this) and the colour
    var $this = $(this),
        color = $this.data('col');

    //Toggle the active class on this link
    $this.toggleClass('active');

    //Remove .main on all .test's
    $(".test").removeClass("main");

    //Map the active link's data-col with a dot attributes to an array
    //Join it up to make a selector
    var selector = $links.filter('.active').map(function(){
        return "."+$(this).data('col');
    }).get().join('');

    //Add the class back on to matches
    $(selector).addClass('main');

    //Finally, prevent the default action
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q0f7w8zj/7/

I am now looking to add the dropdown menu into the equation but can't work out how to integrate it.  Anyone have an example of using a dropdown I can see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some clarification, I have your answer.

To achieve this you'll want to get a bit more complex and maintain an array of filters. Changing the `select`, or clicking a color adjusts our filter array, and we respond accordingly.

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/temule/1/edit?js,output)</kbd>

```
var filters = [];

function filterList () {
  var classes = '.' +  filters.join('.');

  $('.test').removeClass('main');

  if (classes.length > 1) {
    $(classes).addClass('main');
  }
}

function removeFilter(ele) {
  var len = filters.length,
      idx;

  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (filters[i] === ele) {
      idx = i;
      break;
    }
  }

  filters.splice(idx, 1);
}

function addFilter(ele) {
  if (ele) {
    filters.push(ele);
  }
}

var selectIt = (function () {
  var lastSelect;

  return (function (ele) {
    if (lastSelect) {
      removeFilter(lastSelect);
    }

    addFilter(ele);
    lastSelect = ele;
  });
}());


$('.selector').on('change', function (e) {
  var val = $(this).val();

  selectIt(val);
  filterList();
});

$('.mybuttons a').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var el = $(this),
      col = el.data('col');

  if (el.hasClass('active')) {
    removeFilter(col);
  } else {
    addFilter(col);
  }

  el.toggleClass('active');
  filterList();
});
```

```js
var filters = [];

function filterList () {
  var classes = '.' +  filters.join('.');
  
  $('.test').removeClass('main');
  
  if (classes.length > 1) {
    $(classes).addClass('main');
  }
}

function removeFilter(ele) {
  var len = filters.length,
      idx;

  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (filters[i] === ele) {
      idx = i;
      break;
    }
  }

  filters.splice(idx, 1);
}

function addFilter(ele) {
  if (ele) {
    filters.push(ele);
  }
}

var selectIt = (function () {
  var lastSelect;
  
  return (function (ele) {
    if (lastSelect) {
      removeFilter(lastSelect);
    }
    
    addFilter(ele);
    lastSelect = ele;
  });
}());


$('.selector').on('change', function (e) {
  var val = $(this).val();
  
  selectIt(val);
  filterList();
});

$('.mybuttons a').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var el = $(this),
      col = el.data('col');

  if (el.hasClass('active')) {
    removeFilter(col);
  } else {
    addFilter(col);
  }

  el.toggleClass('active');
  filterList();
});
```

```css
.test{height:30px;width:250px;background:lightgrey;margin-bottom:10px;border:black 1px solid;text-align:center}

.link{opacity:.5;}
.main{background:blue;color:white;}
.active{opacity:1;}

.link.red{background:red;color:white;width:50px;height:30px;text-decoration:none;}
.link.green{background:green;green:white;width:50px;height:30px;text-decoration:none;}
.link.yellow{background:yellow;color:black;width:50px;height:30px;text-decoration:none;}
.link.blue{background:blue;color:white;width:50px;height:30px;text-decoration:none;}
.link.orange{background:orange;color:white;width:50px;height:30px;text-decoration:none;}
```

```html
<select class="selector">
  <option value="">--</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<ul class="mybuttons">
  <li><a href="#" data-col="red" class="link red">Red</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-col="green" class="link green">Green</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-col="yellow" class="link yellow">Yellow</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-col="blue" class="link blue">Blue</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-col="orange" class="link orange">Orange</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="test red blue volvo">Red - Blue - Volvo</div>
<div class="test blue">Blue</div>
<div class="test yellow">Yellow</div>
<div class="test blue yellow">Blue - Yellow</div>
<div class="test orange mercedes">Orange - Merceds</div>
<div class="test red">Red</div>
<div class="test yellow volvo">Yellow - Volvo</div>
<div class="test green blue saab">Green - Blue - Saab</div>
<div class="test orange audi saab">Orange - Audi - Saab</div>
<div class="test yellow audi">Yellow - Audi</div>
<div class="test green mercedes">Green - Mercedes</div>
<div class="test blue">Blue</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Very similar, except I am trying to get it to highlight instead of remove the non-matching ones, in the same way that clicking any of the list items does

Comment: I'd like to clarify: Are you trying to convert your color list into a select dropdown, or are you trying to cross reference the two? You should *really* make it more clear as to what you are trying to do in the question.

Comment: I am wanting to cross reference, for example Volvo from the dropdown and red from the list should only highlight 'Red - Blue - Volvo'

Comment: Take another look. Your code needs to become more complex, but at the same time it becomes more maintainable. In the future, you need to be more clear in your question, and remember that most people will *not* take the time to write you an example like this - you need to bring more to the table when you ask for help. I encourage you to read over some of the question guides: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Wow that's a big change, thanks for taking the time to write that.  I'm just going through it now to try and understand what everything is doing